# C++ error: 'QueryFullProcessImageNameA' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mingw

I have this function, and I have #include'd the necessary files, yet I am still getting this error.

OS: Windows 10

Compiler: MinGW

```
string ProcessIdToName(DWORD processId)
{
    string ret;
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(
        PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,
        FALSE,
        processId 
    );
    if (handle)
    {
        DWORD buffSize = 1024;
        CHAR buffer[1024];
        if (QueryFullProcessImageNameA(handle, 0, buffer, &buffSize))
        {
            ret = buffer;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error GetModuleBaseNameA : %lu", GetLastError());
        }
        CloseHandle(handle);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error OpenProcess : %lu", GetLastError());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Use *QueryFullProcessImageName*? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CristiFati Same error with QueryFullProcessImageName.

Comment: Usually this error happens when you include a header A in header B, and at the same time you include header B in header A.

Is that what you do ?

Comment: [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers). I'm having a feeling that a more appropriate solution is to stop using MinGW. It has all the wrong defaults you cannot wait to not ever use again. Like... ANSI encoding.

Comment: Ming is notorious for using outdated Windows SDKs. It is possible that its headers simply dont know about `QueryFullProcessImageName()` at all. If so, you may have to import the function manually at runtime using `GetProcAddress()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you define the macro _WIN32_WINNT to be larger or equal 0x0501 before you include the headers:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
```

Comment: The OP is trying to use `QueryFullProcessImageName()`, not `GetProcessImageFileName()`