# QueryFullProcessImageName was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

[Build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CSYr.png)

Included `#include <windows.h>` and `#include <Psapi.h>` but I keep getting this error.

```sh
 g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
..\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
..\main.cpp:27:64: error: 'QueryFullProcessImageName' was not declared in this scope
    if (QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, buffer, &buffSize)) {
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ error: 'QueryFullProcessImageNameA' was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68297758/c-error-queryfullprocessimagenamea-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Comment: @RichardCritten Unfortunately not.

Comment: Please post all code (and errors) as text in the question. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you, per chance, using a hopelessly outdated SDK? Such as is the default for MinGW.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, using msys64 fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You were probably using classic MinGW, which is quite outdated.

Please use the more up to date MinGW-w64, which exists for both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit.

A recent version can be installed via [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/)'s package manager or you can get a standalone version from https://winlibs.com/.